# aws typescript cdk question: npm run build produces errors

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm following the instructions present here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/hello_world.html

I'm using aws cdk typescript in windows 10

When I run npm run build

I see the following errors

```
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:41:54 - error TS2315: Type 'IsTuple' is not generic.

41 type IndexProperties<T extends { length: number }> = IsTuple<T> extends true
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:53:6 - error TS2456: Type alias 'IsTuple' circularly references itself.

53 type IsTuple<T> = T extends [] ? true : T extends [infer First, ...infer Remain] ? IsTuple<Remain> : false;
        ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:53:65 - error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type.

53 type IsTuple<T> = T extends [] ? true : T extends [infer First, ...infer Remain] ? IsTuple<Remain> : false;
                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:53:84 - error TS2315: Type 'IsTuple' is not generic.

53 type IsTuple<T> = T extends [] ? true : T extends [infer First, ...infer Remain] ? IsTuple<Remain> : false;
                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:96:5 - error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

       ~~~~

node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:131:5 - error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

131     each<
        ~~~~

node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts:165:5 - error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save @types/prettier`
Solved this issue for me